# Replacing Lubuntu in a Lubuntu-Windows dual boot with Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, lubuntu

So, presently I have Lubuntu installed in dual boot with Windows but I wish to change the Lubuntu partition to Arch Linux. So I found [this article on the Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_from_existing_Linux#Replacing_the_existing_system_without_a_LiveCD) which details that. However, the installation part simply says

> Install essentials packages and any other package required to get a system with internet connection up and running in the temporary partition, being careful with the limit of ~700 MB space. When specifying packages to be installed with pacstrap, consider adding the `-c` flag to avoid filling up valuable space by downloading packages to the host system.

So, is

```
# pacstrap /mnt base linux linux-firmware
```

enough to setup a network?

Also,

> Once the new Arch Linux system is installed, fix the bootloader configuration, then reboot into the newly created system, and rsync the entire system to the primary partition.

How would I fix the bootloader configuration?

The rsync article gives me this command

```
# rsync -aAXHv --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} / /path/to/backup
```

What would the path to my backup be since the [original article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Install_Arch_Linux_from_existing_Linux#Replacing_the_existing_system_without_a_LiveCD) doesn't mention anything about a backup?

Should I follow a tutorial for a [regular Arch Linux install](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-install-arch-linux/)?

Comment: Welcome, you could use [arch install](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/archinstall), or follow [the wiki installation guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/installation_guide). IMO your first option is more cumbersome.

Comment: Eventually you could install a friendly arch based distro, like Manjaro, that have graphic installers.

Comment: Thank you, I will try `archinstall` and look into Manjaro.